# Using props in BeforeMount or Mounted- VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lifecycle, vue-props

I have prop in child component -> kpi_kalite[]

**Parent component-> mounted():**

*(This kpi_kalite is created in parent component's data)

```
 axios.get(URL+ "/KPI/").then(response=>{

   console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)))

   this.kpi_kalite.push(response.data[0])

 })
```

I do 'get request' in parent componenet and i push the response.data to kpi_kalite[] (parent component)

And i use this array for props.

Then, I want to do console.log(this.kpi_kalite) in beforeMount or Mounted.
But this props in not using.

```
 methods : {
     set_input(){

            console.log(this.kpi_kalite)
            for(const i in this.kpi_kalite){
                console.log(i)
                console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.kpi_kalite))) // output 
                                                                        //   "undefined"
       }
   }

},
beforeMount() {
    this.set_input()
}
```

console output : undefined

Could you help me? ,Before HTML-css loaded, I need  parent component's data in child component

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. The description is not enough, but it suggests that props aren't set yet at the time when the component is mounted. You physically can't use them in mounted hook. Either postpone the rendering of the component until they are available, or watch them until they are available

Comment: You should wait for `axios response` to render child component, or watch for `kpi_kalite` in child.

Comment: Is the child component rendered after axios is completed or is it always rendered?

Comment: @cafertayyar axios parent component'de mounted kısmında. Yani axios bittikten sonra renderlanıyor. ve html-css yüklenirlen component tagleri ile prop gönderiyor

Comment: If you look at the [link](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f), it says child components are mounted before the parent component is mounted. Therefore, console.log always prints `undefined`. If you render the child component after the axios is completed, console.log will print the value of `kpi_kalite`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [post](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/order-of-lifecycle-hooks-for-parent-and-child/6681/2) by LinusBorg about the order of lifecycle hooks for parent and child:

> There’s nothing weird or wrong about it, it all follows from the
> lifecylce logically.
>
> - beforeCreate() and created() of the parent run first.
> - Then the parent’s template is being rendered, which means the child components get created
> - so now the children’s beforeCreate() and created() hooks execute respecitvely.
> - these child components mount to DOM elements, which calls their beforeMount() and mounted() hooks
> - and only then, after the parent’s template has finished, can the parent be mounted to the DOM, so finally the parent’s beforeMount()
>   and mounted() hooks are called.
>
> END

Also, there is a nice diagram [here](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f).

Child components are mounted before the parent component is mounted. Therefore, `console.log(this.kpi_kalite)` in the child component does not print the data gotten from the `axios` in the parent. So, if you do not render the child component at first, it will not be mounted because it is not created. If you render the child component after the axios is completed, it will be created and mounted. Then, `console.log` will print the value of `kpi_kalite` gotten from the `axios` in the parent.

**ParentComponent**:

`<ChildComponent v-if="renderChildComponent" :kpi_kalite="kpi_kalite" />`

```
data() {
   return {
      kpi_kalite: [],
      renderChildComponent: false,
   };
},
mounted() {
   axios.get(URL+ "/KPI/").then(response=>{
      console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response.data)))
      this.kpi_kalite.push(response.data[0])
      this.renderChildComponent = true;
   })
},
```

Comment: that's so logical. I tried but it is not still working. Output is "undefined"

Comment: Could you share the content of `response.data` if it is possible?

Comment: Sure,
Object
0:
0: {kpi: 1, actual: 100, target: 150, commitment: 300}
1: {kpi: 5, actual: 21, target: 22, commitment: 23}
[[Prototype]]: Object
1:
0: {kpi: 2, actual: 23, target: 20, commitment: 25}
[[Prototype]]: Object
2:
0: {kpi: 3, actual: 25, target: 12, commitment: 23}
[[Prototype]]: Object
3:
0: {kpi: 4, actual: 76, target: 75, commitment: 79}
[[Prototype]]: Object
4:
[[Prototype]]: Object
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: I'm sorry for this format :/

Comment: Did `console.log(response.data)` print this format?

Comment: output:

Object
0:
0: {kpi: 1, actual: 100, target: 150, commitment: 300}
1: {kpi: 5, actual: 21, target: 22, commitment: 23}
[[Prototype]]: Object
1: {0: {…}}
2: {0: {…}}
3: {0: {…}}
4: {}
[[Prototype]]: Object

Comment: i'm missing something.I'm resarching but i couldn't  find how i fix it.
here is the link: https://codepen.io/sudesanil/pen/LYLBMBg

console.log(this.kpi_kalite[i]) ->
`
Proxy {0: {…}, 1: {…}, 2: {…}, 3: {…}, 4: {…}}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Array(5)
0: {0: {…}, 1: {…}}
1: {0: {…}}
2: {0: {…}}
3: {0: {…}}
4: {}
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
`

Comment: In the child component, what does `console.log(this.kpi_kalite)` print in `mounted()`? Also, could you write `props` in the child component please?

Comment: Or, if it is possible, could you add the whole code of both parent and child components in your link https://codepen.io/sudesanil/pen/LYLBMBg

Comment: this is parent component : https://codepen.io/sudesanil/pen/qBjygXz

this is child component: https://codepen.io/sudesanil/pen/rNwrPGQ

Comment: Excuse me for the fact that I asked a lot of questions. I have one more question. In the child component, which one prints `undefined`: `console.log(this.kpi_kalite)` or `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.kpi_kalite)))`?

Comment: console.log(this.kpi_kalite). Beacuse  'for loop' does not run

Comment: Hello @cafertayyar. i lost our chat link. Could you create another one? Because  I want to ask a question about Vue.js created method?

Comment: Now I have a web socket server. The server sends a message to client (in vue.js created function). And I want to use this message in html. But I couldn't do that. @cafertayyar

Comment: Hello @sssss_sssss we can chat here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243556/room-for-cafertayyar-and-sudesanlii